# How to check whether a buffer is writable?

Tags: c, buffer, system-calls

I am writing a shared library that overrides some syscalls. Among them is the `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)` syscall. This library is, of course, in User Space.

So, in my library, I'm catching the `read()` call from the application (which uses `LD_PRELOAD` to preload my lib), do a bunch of things and, at some point, write data to the application buffer (`void *buf`).

**Is there a way for me to check whether the whole application buffer is writable?**

Most of the time it is not an issue but I've come across applications that were so poorly written that they would post read-only buffer in their `read()` call, leading to a segfault in my code when I'm performing a `memcpy()` with their buffer as destination, which makes sense, of course.

Note 1: I'm currently having a look at how the Kernel is handling that situation in the actual `sys_read()` in `fs/read_write.c` but it's not that trivial to understand.

Note 2: The solution should add as little overhead as possible.

Comment: The kernel returns `EFAULT`. Presumably OP wants to do the same in the emulated version.

Comment: @Mat I'm planning to return `-EFAULT`, as R said.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
ssize_t ret = read(fd, dest, amt_to_write);
int err = errno;
close(fd);
if (ret<0 && err==EFAULT) ...
```

Comment: Don't forget that close() could set errno *after* the call to read().

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately, I can't do that, because it's too much overhead. My library focuses on high performance (low latency). Calling `open()`, `read()` and `close()` will result in a huge performance decrease.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tweak of @R. response to mitigate performance hit.

It is not necessary to keep opening and closing /dev/zero.  Just open it
once and leave it open.  Then, every time you are attempting to do
a read, just read one byte to find out if the buffer is writable.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>   

int                
check_writable(char *buf)
{                         
    static int fd;
    int r;

    if (fd == 0) {
            fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
    }

    r = read(fd, buf, 1);

    if (r != 1) {
            return(0);
    }

    return(1);
}             


int
main()
{  
    char *s, wr[8], *rd = "read-only buf";
    int j, r;

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            s = rd;
        }
        else {
            s = wr;
        }

        r = check_writable(s);
        if (r == 0) {
            printf("read-only buffer\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("writable buffer\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although we're saving two syscalls we still have one left. In applications like netperf in ping-pong mode we're performing hundreds of thousands of read()/write() per second. The issue with syscalls is the context switch from User Space to Kernel Space and back. It costs a lot, latencywise. Thanks :)